# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position em renderizar html

Tags: html, python, django, utf-8

Saudações a todos.

Estou tentando renderizar um arquivo html com o Python/Django e estou recebendo o erro "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position" por causa de um comentário acentuado.

O problema não seria grave se eu não precisasse mostrar comentários e descrições nos campos que serão preenchidos por usuários.

Já tentei incluir no código:
{% include "base/js.html, encoding='latin-1', engine='python'" %}

mas o erro persiste e todas as referências que encontrei neste site ou em outros só informam como fazer a leitura de um arquivo em formato csv (que não é o meu caso).

Peço humildemente a sua ajuda para resolver este problema que está me empacando.

Desde já agradeço imensamente toda ajuda que receber.

Comment: Experimenta colocar `# encoding: utf-8` no inicio do ficheiro que tem esses comentários

Comment: Bom dia, Miguel e obrigado pela sua sugestão. Inseri a linha e não deu resultado. O erro persiste.
Atualmente o arquivo CSS.HTML está com o seguinte conteúdo:
{% load static %}
# encoding: utf-8
<!-- Leitor da página de estilos do base.html -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}"

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/UnicodeDecodeError

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu arquivo de template está gravado com a codificação "latin-1" - a nativa do Windows, e não a codificação universal 'utf-8', em que é mais prático escrever projetos de software.

A codificação de acentuação dos arquivos depende da configuração do programa que você está usando para editar os arquivos. (o "notepad" do windows nem permite mudar essa codificiação).

Explore as opções de codificação da ferramenta que você está usando para editar o projeto, abra o seus arquivos de template, mude para "utf-8" e salve de novo.

Provavelmente tem como dizer para o django esperar os arquivos em latin1 em vez de utf-8, passando parâmetros, ou mesmo pelas configurações - mas a dor de cabeça não vale a pena: melhor você ter o projeto todo em utf-9 que ja é o esperado por padrão.

Comment: Realmente tenho usado o Visual Studio para criar os meus arquivos. Depois de abri-los com o Notepad++ e mudar a codificação, funcionou! Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: Só adicionando: eu pude dizer de cara que a codificação é "latin-1" porque sei que é a codificação padrão do Windows em português, e, depois de anos lidando com questões de codificação, sei que o "0xe1" é um valor típico de um acento em português nessa codificação (não sei decor qual) ) - via d regra não tem uma forma de "adivinhar" em qual codificação um arquivo está, a não ser por tentativa e erro.